# Use an external database to login users for Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I am developing a small intranet to serve authenticated-only assets using Laravel 9. I install `laravel:breeze` in order to include login functionality and it works for users that register using breeze form in `/register` route.

I have an external database with the current users that I want to use instead of manually registering one by one.

Is there any approach for achieving this?

Comment: WHat have you tried so far?

Comment: Well I have been reading, my first idea was to use https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticate-a-user-by-id, nonetheless at the end Is the same since the ID should exist in the Laravel database.

Comment: due to lack of any concrete code, this question will be closed. You should show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app which uses another app for the users database. And it sure is using authenticate-by-id feature. Here how it goes:

- A user opens MY_APP and is opening login url which prompt him/her to login using Gmail (might be different in your case)
- MY_APP receives the Gmail account
- Check the existence of the account in MY_APP database: authenticate it if exists, and proceed to the next step if otherwise
- MY_APP checks the existence of the account in the USERS_DB_APP through an API
- If the account is not exists, the login request will be denied
- Otherwise:

  - Save the user record from USERS_DB_APP to my own MY_APP database
  - Then proceed authenticate the user using its just-created id

Your actual case might be different from this. But I hope it can gives you an insight to some level.